# How to make a multiple groups of histogram?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I don't know how this graph is called, but I'm trying to achieve what is in the image (sorry for my poor drawing skills).

I am fairly familiar with gnuplot. If there is another plotting tool more appropriate for this, I can use that too. I have gnuplot code for a single plot of the image (e.g., S1), so if it is just a matter of telling gnuplot to plot several of those graphs side by side I can handle that, I just don't know how and didn't find any simple way of doing it.[image]

**Edit:** I forgot to draw grid ytics
**Edit2:** Making sure it is not a dulpicate

Comment: "How to make a stacked stacked histogram?" - Stuck it twice?

Comment: The question is too broad. I hence marked as duplicate of another question asking for doubly stacked bars in matplotlib.